# ECP/OWA Not accessible, something went wrong

Tags: iis, exchange

I have an Exchange server (2013 SP1 on 2012 R2, CAS and Mailbox Server roles) which was working very fine till this morning. Today I decided to add Windows Server Essentials role in order to enable Remote Web Access (This server has some other roles in our network, hence RWA is needed). Right after enabling it, Exchange stopped and Outlook on clients kept asking users for passwords. I solved it by removing added role. Then problems rose in SSL connectivity and I solved those problems after many hours. Now there is a problem with ECP/OWA. Login page appears, I enter credentials and then get redirected to a page which just says ":-( something went wrong". Nothing more on page or log (Neither IIS logs nor Windows Event Viewer). Checked auth methods, application pool identity, and SSL. Virtual directories are at their places.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Finally fixed it by changing SSL Certificate and changing bindings to the single IP address present on the server in IIS. I first changed bindings, it didn't work. Then changed SSL Certificates. So I'm not sure which change did the trick (maybe both were necessary).

Comment: Please mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Is the Forms Authentication service running? I've seen this problem as a result if that service crashing, etc,  otherwise reset the directories.

Try resetting the virtual directories:

[Reset Client Access Virtual Directories](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff629372(v=exchg.141).aspx)

Comment: Attempted to do this via PowerShell (as I don't have access to ECP), faced this error:
New-PSSession : [exchange.golbarg.local] Connecting to remote server exchange.golbarg.local failed with the following error message:
The WinRM client received an HTTP bad request status (400), but the remote service did not include any other information about the cause of the failure.
(message continues)

Comment: About Forms Authentication: I have enabled it in virtual directory settings. Is there another setting which I should enable/edit?

Comment: After a lot of searching, I could reset virtual directories according to this [link](http://blog.jumlin.com/2010/07/exchange-2010-unable-to-access-console-or-shell/), but it didn't solve problem.